# How can a bad process obtain root by waiting for a user to run a command as sudo?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, process, root, sudo

A comment on this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196664/are-most-linux-systems-that-allow-non-root-users-to-execute-code-straightforward/196667#196667) states:

> The whole linux desktop provides very little protection against bad processes running as the user. A bad process could just watch the keyboard input and wait for the user to run a command as sudo. The bad process now has root without ever being known to the user.

Frankly, this scares me - I was under the impression that `sudo <command>` would only give elevated permissions to run that command, and this method of strict permission management was what made linux much more secure than Windows. I didn't think that `sudo` could be "intercepted".

Are "bad processes" capable of watching the keyboard to obtain root access? If so, how would a process grant itself those permissions when they are for another process? An example of a bad process that could do this along with possible countermeasures would be really appreciated.

Comment: I largely answered this in https://security.stackexchange.com/a/119420/165253 (not a dupe though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `sudo` only grants elevated privileges to the command you run with it.

What the commenter is referring to is that running processes in a Linux desktop session can watch the keystrokes on that desktop session without you knowing. So if you open a terminal window on your desktop, type `sudo <some command>`, and enter your password at the prompt, a malicious program could be keeping track of the keystrokes you typed in and then silently pass the captured password to its own instance of `sudo` to run whatever command it likes as root.

As a simple (non-malicious) example, the program [`screenkey`](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/screenkey) is able to watch the keys you type without needing root privileges. Also, I would bet that global hotkeys (e.g. the <kbd>Super</kbd> key) work in much the same way.

This sounds pretty scary. As for possible countermeasures, I don't really know if there are any once the "bad process" is running on your system. So, all you can really do are preventative measures, like:

- Practice good internet hygiene, i.e. don't download random untrusted executables from the Internet
- Be careful which files you set the execute bit (`chmod +x`) on
- If you have to run an untrusted executable, run it with the lowest possible privileges
  (e.g. `sudo -u nobody <untrusted program>` will run `<untrusted program>` as `nobody`, which has no access to your user's X11 server and therefore can't watch your keystrokes)

Comment: There _is_ a real way to mitigate this, which is to log in directly as root when you need it using a different TTY.

Comment: @forest: you don't necessarily need to login directly as root, you can run sudo from another TTY (not from inside the compromised X session) and you make sure that your login shell doesn't load any rc/profile script from your home directory that you hadn't verified, then an X session key logger won't be able to intercept your key presses.

Comment: Also, Wayland is a thing, and doesn't allow this exact attack anymore.

Comment: @LieRyan Unfortunately it's quite difficult to ensure your shell doesn't load anything that you haven't verified, since they access a _lot_ of potential files. But with enough effort, this could certainly work.